# Get indices of results from scipy.pdist(myArray,metric="jaccard") to map back to original array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance, cosine-similarity

I am trying to calculate jaccard similarity

```
y= 1 - scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X,metric="jaccard")
```

X is a `m x n` matrix and I get a 1-D array of size `m choose 2` as a result of this function. How would I map the similarity values back to obtain a symmetric array or (a non-symmetric array either way is fine) so I can tell which two vectors from X (each row in X is a boolean vector) generated a particular jaccard similarity value in y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.squareform.html) to convert between a full *m x n* distance matrix and the upper triangle:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import distance

m = 100
n = 200
X = np.random.randn(m, n)

d = distance.pdist(X, metric='jaccard')
print(d.shape)
# (4950,)

D = distance.squareform(d)
print D.shape
# (100, 100)
```

Comment: haha I didn't see this sorry. Thanks for your help very well written.

Comment: and how could do the opposite? Let's say that you don't have enough memory and you only compute the distances using the flattened array (pdist). How can someone access the (i, j) element (distance) where i !=j, between two initial vectors?

Comment: This is really lazy and inefficient but it works: i, j  = np.array(np.triu_indices(3, 1)).T[k] where k is the index from the flattened array
@GiorgosPerakis

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(y)` wherein it converts the **condensed form 1-D matrix** obtained from `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(X,metric='jaccard')` into a symmetric matrix so it would be relatively straightforward to obtain indices from there.

So we could do the following :

```
y=1-scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(x,metric='jaccard')
z=scipy.spatial.distance.squareform(y)
```

X is a `m x n` input matrix.
here `y` will be a `1 x (m choose 2)` dimensional matrix (condensed distance matrix)
`z` will be a `m x m` square symmetric matrix